# Adding geo location content to node

Tags: 7, location

I'm looking for a maintained module that allows to add a geo location to a node of a custom content type. I am looking for something that has integration with Google Map API so that it's possible to query the location using an address, ZIP, or name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not a fan of Location and Gmap you can try out [Gmaps](http://drupal.org/project/gmaps) or [Open Layers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers). I am personally not a fan of the Location module and find it bloated and unintuitive. Open Layers has a number of modules that extend it's functionality. Plus it was developed by [Development Seed](http://developmentseed.org/) so you know it's good.

Comment: It's not that I'm not a fan of Location and Gmap, but I need to learn a bit more from them. The Gmaps module was pretty impressive and I think I will stick with that one. Not yet looked on Open Layers, but it looks very interesting. Ty!

Answer (score 3):

If your are using drupal 7, then my favorite option is [openlayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) with [address field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) and [geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield).

The advantage of [openlayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) is that you are not tight to one particular map provider, but you can switch just by changing your options.

You can set [geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) to take the value of the address field, geocode it and store the lon/lat value of the address. You can then draw the locations on the map.
The [geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) works with google or yahoo for geocoding.