# Location module should lookup address before saving

Tags: 7, google-maps, location

This question is related to [Adding geo location content to node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/adding-geo-location-content-to-node).
I'm trying to get a location saved to a node. The [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) module supports this, but I don't like the workflow of this module.

It does the look-up **after** the node is saved, but I would rather do the location look-up **before** the node is saved, e.g. by having a look-up button that, when pressed, queries Google, updates the [gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap), and lets the user see the location before saving and not afterwards, which causes troubles, if the input address couldn't be found.

Do you have any idea on how to address this issue?

Comment: I switched away from the Location and Gmap module because they were a bit hard to work with. I went with OpenLayers module using the geocoder. The OpenLayers module is pretty impressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [OpenLayers Geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers_geocoder) can be the module you are looking for.

> This module extends OpenLayers CCK input widget allowing to mark a location on the map by simply providing its address. A future version will also include support for reverse geocoding.

Comment: Yes, looks interesting. I looked on it yesterday. Best module I have found so far has been http://drupal.org/project/gmaps but sadly not any port going on for drupal7.

Comment: Hello, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. Answers that just contain a link are normally not considered an answer, on SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't help you with the Location module, but [OpenLayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) will map the location before the node is saved.